# Apache2 and proxy_balancer BalanceMember

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I've got this Apache2 site configuration, allowing me to "run Apache as a proxy" of the `localhost:8080` service.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.mydomain.com
    RedirectPermanent / https://foo.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName foo.mydomain.com

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://upstream%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

    <Proxy balancer://upstream>
        # following directive generates the error
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8080
    </Proxy>

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO https

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLEngine               on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/certs/foo.mydomain.com/host.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/certs/foo.mydomain.com/host.key

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_foo_mydomain.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_foo_mydomain.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I restart Apache2 with `service apache2 restart` an error is returned.

I saw that the problem is related to the following directive:

```
BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

If I comment that line, the error is gone and the server is started.
Nevertheless, the proxy is not working.
Syntax should be correct, so I don't exactly know how to solve this.

Of course, both `proxy` and `proxy_balancer` modules are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution allowing me to proxy the `localhost:8080` service.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.mydomain.com
    RedirectPermanent / https://foo.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName foo.mydomain.com

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    SSLEngine               on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/certs/foo.mydomain.com/host.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/certs/foo.mydomain.com/host.key

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_foo_mydomain.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_foo_mydomain.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```